# Odd results from mesh current analysis in a circuit with a diode

Tags: current, diodes, mesh-analysis

I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmub9O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reverse saturation current of the diode is 10^-6 A.

I use mesh current analysis to find the current inside the diode:

[image]

And putting this into WolphramAlpha gives I2 = 0.99...A so the current inside the diode is 0.

But I dont get it why this is happening.

Also if R1 becomes 100Ω there isnt a real solution to the system of the equation from mesh current analysis.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your second equation is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong sign for the voltage across the diode. You should be adding instead of subracting here:
[image]

(Also I'm not sure where the "+1" term comes from...If it's from inverting the Shockley diode equation, then you have it in the wrong place and forgot to multiply it by \$I_s\$, but you can probably ignore it and get an answer that's close enough to correct)